# How can I have the text content of a div overflow in a HTML email template?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm working on this HTML email template and thought I was done until I figured out that GMail and some other e-mail clients strip out the position CSS property.
Since writing html/css for email readers is like going back into the stone ages I'm a little bit stuck on this one.

What I want is to display a score bar which is sort of like a progress bar, with a score text inside of it, like this:

[image: Score 40%]

This works fine until the score becomes really low and the score text doesn't fit inside of the blue container anymore. The text just gets cuts off like so:

[image: Score 10%]

and at 0%:

[image: Score 0%]

Please note that I'm not sure why the word "Score" still shows up in the last one.

What I want is the score text just to overlap into the red part when the text is too long to fit inside of the blue container.

My code is as follows:

```html
<div style="float: left;width: 70%;height: 30px;max-height: 30px;background-color: #f00;color: #fff;font-weight: bold;padding: 0px;font-size: 18px;">
        <div style="float: left;width: 0%;height: 30px;max-height: 30px;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #3c88a7;overflow: visible;">
            <div style="padding-left: 10px; float: left;line-height: 30px;max-height: 30px;">Score 0%</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to solve it with a table, but I walk into the same problem - there seems to be no cross-platform way to make the text overflow the cell.

Any ideas how to solve this, so it works in all the major email clients and webmail clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;background:blue">
    <p style="width:10%;background:red;color:white;white-space: nowrap;">Score: 10%</p>
</div>
```

not very polished, but at least for a code-starter it's fine, i guess

Comment: Elegant. I didn't know about white-space wrapping.

Comment: white-space is not meant to be used like this, but it does a great deal for this problem.

Comment: Great, I got it working with your help. Funny thing is that I had been playing with white-space: nowrap already in the table context. Anyway thanks a lot, you just saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely insane solution. :)

I wrote the SVG to CSS here...

http://jsfiddle.net/coqckyj9/1/

Then converted the SVG to base64 and pasted it into the div background image...

http://jsfiddle.net/coqckyj9/2/

```
<div id='bar' style='width: 100px; height: 20px; background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnPjxyZWN0IGZpbGw9J2JsdWUnIHdpZHRoPSc0cHgnIGhlaWdodD0nMjBweCcgLz48cmVjdCBmaWxsPSdyZWQnIHg9JzRweCcgIHdpZHRoPSc5NnB4JyBoZWlnaHQ9JzIwcHgnIC8+PHRleHQgeD0nMnB4JyB5PScxNnB4JyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScgZm9udC1zaXplPScxOCc+U2NvcmUgNCU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+);'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use just two `div` without positioning. You have to use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent your text from wrapping.

***Example Snippet:***

```css
div.wrap {
    width: 100%; height: 26px; max-height: 26px; 
    background-color: #dd6666; color: #333;
    padding: 0px;
}
div.wrap > div {
    line-height: 26px; max-height: 26px;
    background-color: #3c88a7; padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    width: 30%; white-space: nowrap; color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; 
}
div.d2 > div { width: 5%; }
div.d3 > div { width: 15%; }
div.d4 > div { width: 0%; }
div.d5 > div { width: 60%; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap d1">
    <div>Score 30%</div>
</div>
<br /><div class="wrap d2"><div>Score 5%</div></div>
<br /><div class="wrap d3"><div>Score 15%</div></div>
<br /><div class="wrap d4"><div>Score 0%</div></div>
<br /><div class="wrap d5"><div>Score 60%</div></div>
```